# Zero of energy and chemical potential in a superconductor

Tags: superconductivity, chemical-potential, quasiparticles

I am having trouble grasping some concepts related to how energy is measured in a superconductor. In BCS theory, we are given the energy of the quasi-particles as $E = \sqrt{\varepsilon^2 + \Delta^2}$ in which $\varepsilon = \frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m} - \mu$, with $\mu$ being the chemical potential. As such, we find the quasi-particles exist with a minimum energy of $\Delta$.

My questions are as follows:

1. What is the zero of energy in a BCS superconductor? In other words, when we say that the quasi-particles have a minimum energy of $\Delta$, are we saying that the quasi-particles exist at an energy that is at least $\Delta$ above the ground state? So the energy of the ground state equals zero? Does this mean that $\mu$ is measured relative to the energy of the ground state?
2. What species of particle does the chemical potential $\mu$ control? Does $\mu$ control the number of Cooper pairs in the superconductor or the number of electrons in general? Can there be two different chemical potentials for Cooper pairs and the quasi-particles?